# Compare two list of string array

Tags: arrays, string, matlab

How do I solve, Two string arrays `J=(nx1)` and `K=(mx1)`, with same values, if some of the values are missing in J then I need to create a new array for those missing values `L=(ix1)` ; for example:
`J={Two_Headlights
one_engine
four_wheels
two_seats
two_seatbelts}`

`K={Two_Headlights
one_engine
one_gear
one_break
one_clutch 
four_wheels
two_seats
two_seatbelts}`

then I would like to create a new array for those missing values in J;
`L={one_gear
one_break
one_clutch}`

I have tried using the for loop by using setdiff and aswell as using strcmp, but I dont know where I am going wrong, I am not able to get the result.

Comment: Where is your code? What is the output that you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you missed putting the single quotation for the strings when writing your question.
The `setdiff(A,B)` function will return the data in `A` that is not in `B`. So your first argument must be `K`.

```
J={'Two_Headlights','one_engine','four_wheels','two_seats','two_seatbelts'};

K={'Two_Headlights','one_engine','one_gear','one_break','one_clutch','four_wheels','two_seats','two_seatbelts'}; 
L = setdiff(K,J);
```